# Getting Error in chol.default(K) : the leading minor of order 5 is not positive definite with betareg

Tags: r, regression, lm, beta

I'm trying to fit a `beta` `regression` model using the `betareg` `function` of the `betareg` `package` to these data:

```
df <- data.frame(category=c("c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c3","c3","c3","c3","c3","c3","c4","c4","c4","c4","c4","c4","c5","c5","c5","c5","c5","c5"),
                 value=c(6.6e-18,0.0061,0.015,1.1e-17,4.7e-17,0.0032,0.29,0.77,0.64,0.59,0.39,0.72,0.097,0.074,0.073,0.08,0.06,0.11,0.034,0.01,0.031,0.041,4.7e-17,0.025,0.58,0.14,0.24,0.29,0.55,0.15),stringsAsFactors = F)

df$category <- factor(df$category,levels=c("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5"))
```

With this command:

```
library(betareg)
fit <- betareg(value ~ category, data = df)
```

And I'm getting this `error`:

```
Error in chol.default(K) : 
  the leading minor of order 5 is not positive definite
In addition: Warning message:
In sqrt(wpp) : NaNs produced
Error in chol.default(K) : 
  the leading minor of order 5 is not positive definite
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In betareg.fit(X, Y, Z, weights, offset, link, link.phi, type, control) :
  failed to invert the information matrix: iteration stopped prematurely
2: In sqrt(wpp) : NaNs produced
```

Is there any solution or does a beta regression simply cannot be fitted to these data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fitting a beta distribution to the data in category 1 will be very challenging with three observations being essentially zero. With rounding to five digits: 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00320, 0.00610, 0.01500. It's not clear to me whether this category should be modeled in the same way as the others.

In category 4 there is another observation that is numerically zero although the other observations are somewhat larger: 0.00000, 0.01000, 0.02500, 0.03100, 0.03400, 0.04100.

Omitting category 1 at least allows to estimate the model without numerical problems. Whether or not the asymptotic inference is a good approximation for two parameters from six observations per group is another question. The precision does not seem to be the same across groups though.

```
betareg(value ~ category | 1, data = df, subset = category != "c1")
## Call:
## betareg(formula = value ~ category | 1, data = df, subset = category != 
##     "c1")
## 
## Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
## (Intercept)   categoryc3   categoryc4   categoryc5  
##      0.2634      -2.2758      -4.4627      -1.0206  
## 
## Phi coefficients (precision model with log link):
## (Intercept)  
##       2.312  
betareg(value ~ category | category, data = df, subset = category != "c1")
## Call:
## betareg(formula = value ~ category | category, data = df, subset = category != 
##     "c1")
## 
## Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
## (Intercept)   categoryc3   categoryc4   categoryc5  
##      0.2566      -2.6676      -4.0601      -0.9784  
## 
## Phi coefficients (precision model with log link):
## (Intercept)   categoryc3   categoryc4   categoryc5  
##      2.0849       3.5619      -0.2308      -0.1376
```